# Can someone explain how to use JWT authentication for ReactJs taking the following code as reference?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth, passport.js

I am trying to understand how this function is working so that I can make a similar function for jwt authentication via google login

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = () => {

        const requestHeaders: HeadersInit = new Headers();
        requestHeaders.set("Accept", "application/json");
        requestHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        requestHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", `${true}`);
      //   requestHeaders.set("x-access-token", '(await getFromStorage("user"))?.token');
        requestHeaders.set('Authorization', `Bearer + ${localStorage.getItem('login')}`)

      fetch("http://localhost:8080/v2/login/success", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: requestHeaders,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
          throw new Error("authentication has been failed!");
        })
        .then((resObject) => {
          setUser(resObject.user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
    getUser();
  }, []);
```